# Access the microphone without Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, web-applications, microphone

Is there a possible way to access the computer microphone from a web document (open in a browser) without have to go through Adobe Flash ?

Comment: You need to get your title and question to agree - without JavaScript or without Flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either wait a few years for the [W3C Media Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) to be implemented in browsers (and deal with whatever user permission dialogs are necessary for those to be accessible to your Javascript), or develop your own plugin to make that data available, which the user then has to install.

Other than that, there's no way to access that data without an existing plugin such as Flash.